# Wordpress and the W3 Total Cache minifier

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, caching

I have installed the W3 total cache for my WordPress network and everything is working well except for the Minifier section.

When put to "Auto" the plugin needs access to this path:

```
/wp-content/cache/minify/000006/M9AvLqnMSQUA.css
```

However it breaks because Wordpress is redirecting it to the 404.php template thinking its a page / permalink.

Is there something I can put in my .htaccess or change a permission to allow direct access to this path so the minify scripts can work?

Here is what I have in my .htaccess file so far (including all the total cache settings)

```
# BEGIN W3TC Minify cache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/wp-content/cache/minify/[0-9]+/w3tc_rewrite_test$ /wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php?w3tc_rewrite_test=1 [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Minify cache

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # uploaded files
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
    RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had this same issue for a few months now and I think I have solved it. It is to do with file permissions.

To find out if this is the problem for you try navigating to http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php. If you get a 404 then it's probably a file permission issue. You should get a blank page for this.

Check the file permissions, if any of the plugin directories are set to 775 and/or if any of the files are set to 664 then this points to a permission error also.

**To fix:**

Change the permissions of all these folders to **755** make sure to include all subdirectories, folders only.

```
/wp-content/plugins
/wp-content/cache
/wp-content/w3tc-config
```

[image: Changing directory permissions]

Also make sure the files are set correctly to **644** by using the apply to files only in filezilla

```
/wp-content/plugins
/wp-content/cache
/wp-content/w3tc-config
```

[image: Changing file permissions]

You will likely have to empty the minify cache after doing this, and depending on whether it works straight away, you may have to redo the permissions after emptying the cache and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comments which is how W3TC determines where to put its rewrite rules - check out line 19 of `/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/inc/functions/rule.php` (assuming you have the latest version).

Basically WordPress is intercepting the request before it gets to the W3TC rewrite and you get a 404. By moving this section below the W3TC rules, they will catch the rewrite before it makes it to the WordPress sections (the `[L]` at the end of the rewrite says that a match is the **[L]**ast rule to be followed), properly rewriting the URL to your minified cache and not resulting in a 404.

The "official" (automatically generated) WordPress block in my multisite install looks like the following, and should be the last set of rewrite rules in your `.htaccess` file, below the W3TC sections. Make sure to include the comments as other plugins may look for them when updating this file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Hmm Im afraid even with those changes I am still getting redirected to the themes 404 page. I have updated my .htaccess above.

Comment: Can you post your new complete .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes I updated the question with my new .htaccess file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried re-saving your permalink structure or turning minify rewriting on and off again? It looks like you might be missing the rewrite there resulting in a 404.

Comment: Just re-read your question and my original suggestion was wrong - the URL you are referencing doesn't exist, it should be a rewrite to W3TC to serve the minified files. In the plugin config have you tried to disable "minify rewrite"? Do you have admin/email notifications on for errors?